# aurelia view-model properties inside a promise "then" function

Tags: javascript, promise, aurelia

I'm trying to access my view-model properties and bindings into a "then" function of a promise just like this :

```
let that = this;
this.getDate().then(data => {
    that.binding.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    console.log(that.property);
});
```

The thing is "this" is undefined so how am I supposed to get those?

Comment: if `this` is undefined, then `this.getDate` couldn't possibly work, because arrow functions work that way - seems like the error you are having is not what you think

Comment: I've edited my op. Even if I declared a "cached this" I can't access to it how am I supposed to access value from it?

Comment: `let that = this;` ... and then you don't use `that` ...

Comment: I did a quick edit because I tested it out like 30 minutes ago

Comment: if `that` is now undefined, then how can `this.getDate` even work :p

Comment: there's some sort of transpiling going on perhaps? and it's failing?

Comment: that and this works but once I'm in an arrow function that can't be access and this is undefined, I'll try to remove the source map in chrome inspection to see how's the transpilling

Comment: Hmm I found a way to get this by instead of using arrow functions, using function(data) {...work...}.bind(this) is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: I tried to do (data) => to set the "inner" scope to the "outer" scope but it still can't access the that variable nor this

Comment: Alright, turns out it was indeed the transpiler + I didn't use (data) =>. In debug I was trying to access this but it was in fact _this5. I'll create a solution to explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was trying to read "this" in the debugger when the variable I should have try to read was _this5 which was created by babel transpiller for ES5.

Comment: actually, you are wrong about the first error ... arrow functions are weird. If you have a single, simple argument as in your case, `(data) =>` is identical to `data =>` ... it's only if you have two or more arguments that the `()` are required, or if you are doing something fancy like destructuring `({data}) =>` which would result in `data` being the passed in objects `data` property

Comment: You're right. I'm not familliar with ES6 and I try to adapt myself to it.